# oh-my-zsh (terminal) how to change prefix & suffix of new prompt window

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, zsh, oh-my-zsh

Installed on my Mac running Yosemite is a few packages to make life in the terminal (iTerm 2) a bit better. I have **oh-my-zsh** (only plugin I have id **antigen** for oh-my-zsh) along with [**oh-my-git**](https://github.com/arialdomartini/oh-my-git) installed.

Currently when I run iTerm 2 or Terminal and I'm not in a git repo, I see this:

`james.mosier@fs215:~%                                  9:59 james.mosier@fs215`

...in image form below:

[image: screenshot]

---

#### What I am trying to do is:

1.) remove the timestamp & computer name at the end of the input
2.) change the prefix to (at the very least) remove the `%` sign

I know my way around the `.zshrc`, `.profile`, `.bash_profile` fairly well, at least for what I want to accomplish above. I just can't seem to find where $PS1 is set with the output below, which I assume is what I should be looking for.

#### What I've tried...

I have tried to do `echo $PS1` which gives me `$(build_prompt)`, then I do `echo $(build_prompt)` which gives me the output of `%n@%m:%~%#`. I cannot find this text anywhere within my `.zshrc`, [`oh-my-zsh.sh`](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/blob/master/oh-my-zsh.sh), [`.prompt.sh`](https://github.com/arialdomartini/oh-my-git/blob/master/prompt.sh), or [`.base.sh`](https://github.com/arialdomartini/oh-my-git/blob/master/base.sh)files.

I have also found the `$(build_prompt)` but it doesn't appear to contain the formatting for the line I'm looking to change (`$(build_prompt)`is located in `prompt.sh` in my oh-my-git plugin, [file found here](https://github.com/arialdomartini/oh-my-git/blob/master/prompt.sh))

#### Conclusion

In the files I have linked above, is there a pattern or string I can alter to change my terminal's prefix and suffix? Ideally I'd like to get rid of the suffix completely and alter the prefix to just be whatever the default terminal prefix is or `~`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution after much investigation. It might be a bit speclialized towards my situation, unless you happen to be using antigen, oh-my-zsh, and oh-my-git. But anyway...

The `PS1` variable (**prefix**) is in the `theme-and-appearance.zsh`, located in `.antigen/repos/https-COLON--SLASH--SLASH-github.com-SLASH-robbyrussell-SLASH-oh-my-zsh.git/lib`

The existing entry is `PS1="%n@%m:%~%# "` and I changed it to `PS1="$ [%~] "`

---

The **suffix** was a bit harder to find. In the `.antigen/repos/https-COLON--SLASH--SLASH-github.com-SLASH-arialdomartini-SLASH-oh-my-git-themes.git/oppa-lana-style.zsh-theme` file, I found this variable and commented it out completely: `RPROMPT='%{$reset_color%}%T %{$fg_bold[white]%} %n@%m%{$reset_color%}`